# how to make banner responsive and scale properly - by not using background property

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image, background-size

Is there a way I can make a banner responsive and the image scale properly..i.e the height remains same with following structure

```
<div class="banner">
    <img src="/img/banner1.png" alt="Banner">
</div>
```

I know with css we can make the image background image for class banner. But is it possible to have the effect of

```
background-position, background-size
```

with above structure.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `img` a try to add this css to your `.banner` :

```
.banner { 
    background-image: url('/img/banner1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: this is what I don't want. I know it can be achieved if we  use background-imag. I am unable to do this inline also.

Comment: Did you try `img { width: 100%;  height: auto; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following class to your image:

```
<img src="/img/banner1.png" width="460" height="345" class="responsive">
```

CSS:

```
.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Also... Replace the width and height attributes to the size of banner1.png.

On a separate note, if you are unaware of Bootstrap, checkout their Responsive Framework, a simple class "img-responsive", will make all images responsive.